# Python create windows exe with a config file to pass username and password

Tags: python, post, python-requests, exe, pyinstaller

I have a python script for checking re-investment settings on a popular bitcoin mining site and I would like to use Pyinstaller to create a windows .exe file to distribute. However, in the payload section where I pass an email and password, the user would not be able to edit that.  So I need to be able to generate the .exe and a config file where the user can edit their email and password information.

I am using requests (session) and the example payload is like this:

```
    payload = {
        'action': 'dashboard.php',
        'email': 'user@email.com',
        'password': 'abc123-pass'
    }
```

I need to change these to variables and have them read from a config file when the exe is executed.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Well each user of the .exe needs to be able to edit a config file to set a variable for their email and pw.  Currently, I can only compile it with a username and pw...  So I do not know how to create the variables and pass them from a config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply use configparser or (ConfigParser for Python2.7) to access configuration files.
Then you can create a configuration file like:

```
# This is the configuration file for my script for user X 
[DEFAULT] 
action =  dashboard.php 
email = user@email.com 
password = abc123-pass`
```

In your script

```
import configparser
my_config_parser = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
my_config_parser.read('name of your configuration file')
payload = {
    'action': my_config_parser.get('DEFAULT','action'),
    'email': my_config_parser.get('DEFAULT','email'),
    'password': my_config_parser.get('DEFAULT','password')
}
```

The configuration file you need to send with the exefied script.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking to do.   (new to python)

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass options `--exclude-module settings add-data settings.py;.` to PyInstaller. That way *settings.py* will end up in the directory with compiled application and can be imported in usual way.